# AngularJS ng-grid not displaying any data, why?

Tags: angularjs

I'm going to turn a REST dataset into an ng-grid component. I'm using the basic demo which ships with ng-grid component but using an $http.get to populate the grid:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js"></script>


<script language="javascript">
                var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);


                app.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {

                      $http.get('http://server/json').
                        success(function(data) {
                             $scope.myData = data;

                        });

                    });



                    $scope.gridOptions = {
                            data: 'myData',
                            enableRowSelection: false,
                            enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
                            multiSelect: false, 
                            columnDefs: [
                              { field: 'name', displayName: 'name', enableCellEdit: false } ,
                              { field: 'surname', displayName: 'surname', enableCellEdit: false } 
                            ]
                          };

                });


               </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Hello">

    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried the above code, however the REST service is not invoked and the grid is displayed as a blank div. I've tried with several variations of the $http.get method with no luck. 
Any help ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `gridOptions` seem to be set outside the controller. Move it inside and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
http://server/json
```

to the endpoint you're calling to actually get the data. ://server/json is just a placeholder for your actual endpoint. The div is empty because there's no data there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well I've added in the question a fake endpoint name, to hide the actual name that was quite long.